# Update my website from a github repository

Tags: github

I use a website for testing purposes. Part of what I test is a public repository on GitHub. What I would like to do is have my site periodically check the repository and pull any changes to a folder in my site.

I'm using a LAMP server, is there some php and a cronjob that I can use to check and get the files from the repository?

Comment: Does cron need to do anything more than `git fetch` the remote? Even so, it might be easier to work with appropriate hook (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks/) Github allows. See here for a [simple PHP example](https://gist.github.com/619858) that executes a auto-pull if the Github repository gets updated.